# Manipulate Filters in Javascript

Tags: web-part, javascript, filter, library

Is there any code in JavaScript which allow to manipulate filter to a library webpart?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented API that would help to filter ListViewWebPart using JavaScript. The best way to achieve this would be to use query string parameter filtering, like described here http://www.sharemuch.com/2013/11/18/sharepoint-silly-questions-filtering-list-view-with-query-string-parameters/

You could redirect from JavaScript with `window.navigate()` to a page with appropriate query string parameters.